# Comparing two dictionaries and printing key value pair in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
a= { "fruits": ["apple", "banana"] }
b = { "fruits": ["apple", "carrot"]}
```

Now I want to print the differences. And I want to 
In this case the output should be

```
{'fruits' : 'carrot'}
```

also if the keys have changed - suppose if has changed to

```
b = { "toy": "car"}
```

then the output should be

```
{ "toy": "car"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't actually have those dictionaries. Dictionaries don't work like that.

Comment: Do you want `'vegetables'` to be printed as well since it's a key in `a` not present in `b`?

Comment: this is not valid `a = { 'fruits': 'apple' 'grape', 'vegetables': 'carrot'}`

Comment: @yopy, *technically* it's "valid", but it's probably not what OP intended :)

Comment: @yopy two adjacent string literals concatenate, so `'fruits': 'apple' 'grape'` is just `'fruits': 'applegrape'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `dict.viewitems` might be a good method to look at.  This will allow us to easily see which key/value pairs are in `a` that aren't in `b`:

```
>>> a = { 'fruits': 'apple' 'grape', 'vegetables': 'carrot'}
>>> b = { 'fruits': 'banana'}
>>> a.viewitems() - b.viewitems()  # python3.x -- Just use `items` :)
set([('fruits', 'applegrape'), ('vegetables', 'carrot')])
>>> b['vegetables'] = 'carrot'  # add the correct vegetable to `b` and try again.
>>> a.viewitems() - b.viewitems()
set([('fruits', 'applegrape')])
```

We can even get a handle on what the difference actually is if we use the symmetric difference:

```
>>> a.viewitems() ^ b.viewitems()
set([('fruits', 'applegrape'), ('fruits', 'banana')])
```

You could also do something similar with `viewkeys` (`keys` on python3.x) if you're only interested in which keys changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! viewitems was much of help to me :)

Answer (score 1):

As to the differences, You can use a dictionary comprehension to filter only `b` keys which are in `a`:

```
>>> {key: b[key] for key in b if key in a}
{'fruits': 'banana'}
```

---

To the second part, "if the keys have changed", `{'froot'}` isn't a valid dictionary, and keys are immutable. So it's not possible.