# Obtain records based on matching key value pairs and comparing date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, key-value, date-comparison

I have a following collection in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39f8"),
    "name" : "swetha",
    "nameId" : 123,
    "source" : "Blore",
    "sourceId" : 10,
    "LastUpdate" : "10-Oct-2018"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39f9"),
    "name" : "swetha",
    "nameId" : 123,
    "source" : "Mlore",
    "sourceId" : "11",
    "LastUpdate" : "11-Oct-2018"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbc86e5c16a27f1e1bd39fa"),
    "name" : "swathi",
    "nameId" : 124,
    "source" : "Mlore",
    "sourceId" : "11",
    "LastUpdate" : "9-Oct-2018"
}
```

I am a beginner to Python and want to compare the **'LastUpdate'** between the above records based on matching **'name'** or **'nameId'** and want to push the record with latest date to another collection. E.g. **name:'Swetha'** is same in first two records. So compare **'LastUpdate'** between them and output the record with latest date.

I have written following code to read data records from MongoDB and to print. I didn't understand how to compare records within a same key and compare their timestamp though I referred few resources on Google.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient

try: 
    client = MongoClient() 
    print("Connected successfully!!!") 
except:   
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB") 

# database 
db = client.conn
collection = db.contactReg
df = collection.find()
for row in df:
    print(row)
```

Links that are ref

[Is there a better way to compare dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911273/is-there-a-better-way-to-compare-dictionary-values)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87276/how-to-compare-values-from-a-column-in-attribute-table-with-values-in-dictionary

[Comparing two dictionaries and printing key value pair in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004893/comparing-two-dictionaries-and-printing-key-value-pair-in-python) and few more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is an aggregation. This might look big but once you get the hang out of mongo aggregations you'll get comfortable.

```python
df = collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": 1,
            "nameId": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "sourceId": 1,
            "LastUpdate": 1,
            "LastUpdateArray": {
                "$split": [
                    "$LastUpdate",
                    "-"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "nameId": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "sourceId": 1,
            "LastUpdate": 1,
            "LastUpdateArray": 1,
            "LastUpdateMonth": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$LastUpdateArray",
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "nameId": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "sourceId": 1,
            "LastUpdate": 1,
            "Year": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$LastUpdateArray",
                    2
                ]
            },
            "Date": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$LastUpdateArray",
                    0
                ]
            },
            "Month": {
                "$switch": {
                    "branches": [
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Jan"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "01"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Feb"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "02"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Mar"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "03"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Apr"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "04"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "May"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "05"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Jun"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "06"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Jul"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "07"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Aug"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "08"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Sep"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "09"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Oct"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Nov"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "11"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$LastUpdateMonth",
                                    "Dec"
                                ]
                            },
                            "then": "12"
                        }
                    ],
                    "default": "01"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "nameId": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "sourceId": 1,
            "LastUpdate": 1,
            "Year": 1,
            "Date": 1,
            "Month": 1,
            "DateString": {
                "$concat": [
                    "$Year",
                    "-",
                    "$Month",
                    "-",
                    "$Date"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "nameId": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "sourceId": 1,
            "LastUpdate": 1,
            "Date": {
                "$dateFromString": {
                    "dateString": "$DateString"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "Date": -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "name": {
                "$first": "$name"
            },
            "nameId": {
                "$first": "$nameId"
            },
            "source": {
                "$first": "$source"
            },
            "sourceId": {
                "$first": "$sourceId"
            },
            "LastUpdate": {
                "$first": "$LastUpdate"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$first": "$Date"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "nameId": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "sourceId": 1,
            "LastUpdate": 1
        }
    }
])
```

The first 5 steps of aggregation, I tried to convert it into a date and then sort descending by date. In group by I grouped with name and took the first that comes with that name.

Hope this helps.

I'm assuming what you need is duplicate records and I'm taking the first one that comes. Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26985011/7630071

```python
df = collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            },
            "data": {
                "$push": {
                    "nameId": "$nameId",
                    "source": "$source",
                    "sourceId": "$sourceId",
                    "LastUpdate": "$LastUpdate"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": {
                "$ne": null
            },
            "count": {
                "$gt": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the solution. But i was expecting doing with for loop or using sets. could u just share the code only to group with name and return records with matching name. no need of comparing date.

Comment: You mean you need only duplicate records like `"name": "swetha"`

Comment: yes!! i want to return all records which have same name @Sivesh Gsk

Comment: I've added another query in the answer.

Comment: code shows error :' "$ne": null
NameError: name 'null' is not defined' but when null is put in the qotes - "null" output appears.

Comment: i want both duplicate records to be displayed not just the one that comes first. How to do that? @Sivesh Gsk

Comment: remove last two projects in the query. Edited the answer.

Comment: yeah..got it!! Thanks for having patience to answer all my questions.